# Function stack during recursive calls

Tags: stack

Here is the function:

```
 fun(int n)
    {
      if(n>0)
       {
         fun(n-1)+fun(n-2);
         //does both functions have same stack//
        }
      else
       {
          return 0;
        }
   }
```

I need to know how stacks are created for this function when called repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,
Its not about how many stack does processor maintains, its more about how it maintains such stack.

[image]

Here, let us understand it with an example for which n=3. first fun(3) is called, which will call fun(2), which will call fun(1) and so on (as calling for fun(n-1)). So, the stack entry will be fun(3)->fun(2)->fun(1)->fun(0). As the argument is zero function will return "0". So, fun(0) is poped out from the stack. further the remaining call that is fun(n-2) is performed for n=1, for which function is returning no value. so, the execution will be done until end of function. Then similarly, fun(1) will be poped from the stack. so at this point stack has following value fun(3)->fun(2). after returning to fun(2), the next call of fun(2) (that is fun(n-2)) is called. and is added to the stack. now, stack value will be fun(3)->fun(2)->fun(0). and the same way whole code is executed. Thus it maintains the same stack for such call.

Hopefully, Helpfull.